# If & is not found at the end then replace everything

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex as such

```
eregi_replace("s=.*&","",$section->urlToThreads);
```

What it does is replace everything with `''` which starts with `'s='` and ends with `'&'`

What I want to do is also if an '&' is not found after the 's=' till the end of the string, then replace everything from 's=' till the end of the string with ''

E.g.

**test.php?s=12232dsd23423&t=41** would become **test.php?t=41**

And

**test.php?t=41&s=12232dsd23423** would become **test.php?t=41**

Comment: Could you show us how you've solved it for future readers?

Comment: @M42 - updated question above

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh: You should rather add your solution as an *answer* (you can answer your own question) and remove it from the question. You can then accept your own answer to mark the question as solved. Don't write "solved" in the title of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION - WITHOUT REGEX**

```
$str = $section->urlToThreads;
                        $url = '';
                        $url = $section->urlToThreads;
                        $pos = strpos( $str,'s=');
                        if ($pos)
                        {
                            $pos_ampersand =  strpos( $str,'&',$pos);

                            if ($pos_ampersand) //if ampersand is found after s=
                            {
                                $url = substr($str, 0, $pos) . substr($str, $pos_ampersand+1, strlen($str));
                            }
                            else // if no ampersand found after s=
                            {
                                $url = substr($str, 0, $pos-1);
                            }
                        }
                        $section->urlToThreads = $url;
```

Comment: I opted for just writing a script and got it

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `&` optional and allow only non-`&` characters to match in-between. Also, use a word boundary so only `s=` is matched (and not a substring of `links=`):

```
"\bs=[^&]*&?"
```

But you should not be using `ereg` any more. Update to `preg`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\bs=[^&]*&?/', '', $section->urlToThreads);
```

Comment: I also added a '?' before the s= just to remove the remaining ampersand in before the s in the second example above. Its working fine now. I hope thats ok.

Comment: oops, your solution not working for example 1 above. it wipes t=41 also

Answer (score 1):

If it were preg_replace I would do:

```
preg_replace('@(\?)s(=[^&]*)?&?|&s(=[^&]*)?@', '\\1', $section->urlToThreads);
```

Some tests:

```
$tests = array(
    'test.php?s',
    'test.php?s=1',
    'test.php?as=1',
    'test.php?s&as=1',
    'test.php?s=1&as=1',
    'test.php?as=1&s',
    'test.php?as=1&s=1',
    'test.php?as=1&s&bs=1',
    'test.php?as=1&s=1&bs=1'
);
foreach($tests as $test){
    echo sprintf("%-22s -> %-22s\n", $test, preg_replace('@(\?)s(=[^&]*)?&?|&s(=[^&]*)?@', '\\1', $test));
}
```

Output:

```
test.php?s             -> test.php?
test.php?s=1           -> test.php?
test.php?as=1          -> test.php?as=1
test.php?s&as=1        -> test.php?as=1
test.php?s=1&as=1      -> test.php?as=1
test.php?as=1&s        -> test.php?as=1
test.php?as=1&s=1      -> test.php?as=1
test.php?as=1&s&bs=1   -> test.php?as=1&bs=1
test.php?as=1&s=1&bs=1 -> test.php?as=1&bs=1
```

Comment: in the first example it is leaving the an '&' before 't=41' and in the second example it is leaving an '&' after the 't=41'

Comment: Yes, I've posted a quick workaround for this. A leading `?&` or a trailing `&` should be OK, right.

Answer (score 0):

`s=.*(?:&|$)` check for `&` **or** end of line/string.